# Pass data via ajax to dialog Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, dialog

I am trying to post data from my form to a jquery dialog that loads external content.

I am serializing the form data which works (appears in the url) but the dialog won't open:

```
      $("#wavajax button").click(function() {
  $.post({url: 'player/index.php', data: $("#wavajax").serialize(), 
         success: function (data) {

                     $("#recordingdialog").load("player/index.php", [], function(){
               $("#recordingdialog").dialog("open");

                 }
  });
  return false;
});
```

What  am I doing wrong, am I going about it the right way???

Comment: Are you creating the dialog before this?  Also unsure why you're doing a POST then a GET of the same URL?

Comment: I am trying to post the data to player/index.php and have that page open up in a dialog with the posted data within

Comment: the ui dialog should open kind regardless if `#recordingdialog` is a div which is placed in your markup and you including all dialog ui dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're after:

```
$("#wavajax button").click(function() {
  $.post('player/index.php', $("#wavajax").serialize(), function (data) {
       $("#recordingdialog").html(data).dialog("open");
  });
  return false;
});
```

You're already getting the HTML content back from the POST (or at least I would think this is the case), so just put that response in the `#recordingdialog` using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and then make the dialog call.  If you're not previously creating a dialog with options, then just `.dialog()` will suffice, [`.dialog('open')`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-open) is intended for when you created the dialog earlier with various options and want to now open it, like this:

```
$("#recordingdialog").dialog({
  //other options, width, height, etc...
  autoOpen: false
});
```

[You can find a full list of these options here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: This works nicely. But when I close the dialog and click to open it again nothing happens any ideas why o masterful nick

Comment: @user that shouldn't be the case...is there anything else messing with that `#recordingdialog` element?

Comment: Yep I had a header included in the top of the player/index.php file. removed it and everything is fine. YOU THE MAN!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe a better idea to first display the dialog and load the content.

```
$('#recordingdialog').dialog('destroy'); // just in case
$('#recordingdialog').dialog({
   position: 'center',
   // some more options
   open:  function(e, ui){
        $.post('player/index.php', data: $("#wavajax").serialize(),function (data){   
              $("#recordingdialog").html(data);   
        });
   }
});
```

within your click handler.

[UI Dialog Doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: This approach leaves a blank dialog waiting for the content to load, then will flash when it does, I don't believe this is an approach that should be used....also check your `$.post()` call, it's not valid :)

Comment: I guess this approach is way better than just letting nothing happen after pressing the button. It's maybe a good idea to insert some kind of `loading` gif into the dialog on opening.

Comment: Your current answer throws a javascript syntax error, so it's not better yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have it working with this:

```
      $("#recordingdialog").dialog({
  //other options, width, height, etc...
     modal: true,
      bgiframe: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 550,
      width: 550,
      draggable: true,
      resizeable: true,
      title: "Play Recording",});


$("#wavajax button").click(function() {
  $.post('player/index.php', $("#wavajax").serialize(), function (data) {
       $("#recordingdialog").html(data).dialog("open");
  });
  return false;
});
```

Thanks Nick! But have one issue. When I close the dialog and click on the button to open it again nothing happens why not???